# Grails group query works with Mysql but fails with SQLServer

Tags: mysql, sql-server, grails, hql

I am working with Grails and I have this query that works fine when I use MySql but it fails when I use SQL Server

```
def list = Ticket.executeQuery("select t.expertice from Ticket t where t.currentStatus = 1 and t.team = 11 group by t.expertice")
```

```
The errot I get:
ERROR GrailsExceptionResolver - Column 'expertice.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Column 'expertice.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:285)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:93)
        at com.bayer.bbs.emea.web.wbt.TestController$_closure4_closure13.doCall(TestController.groovy:65)
        at com.bayer.bbs.emea.web.wbt.TestController$_closure4.doCall(TestController.groovy:29)
        at com.bayer.bbs.emea.web.wbt.TestController$_closure4.doCall(TestController.groovy)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: As the error says Sql server won't allow a group by without aggregate functions. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The error does not refer to the query that you posted.

Comment: Please investigate the formatting options available to you - this question is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works... the field expertice is a Grais entity.

```
select t.expertice.id 
from Ticket t 
where t.currentStatus = 1 
      and t.team = 11 
group by t.expertice.id
```

I included `.id` and it works without error both MySql an SQLServer.